# Strange many to many relationshoip

Tags: database

I am not sure what the best way to handle this would be, so I am looking for some input. I have 3 tables, lets call them

```
User
WidgetA
WidgetB
```

For reasons that I don't want to get into the two widget tables can't be mixed, and they are from 2 different sources. WidgetA uses a GUID for a key and WidgetB uses an auto increment. The user will be allowed to pick their favourite widgets from either A or B. What is the best way to set this up? Should I have two favourites tables, that join the widgets to user that way I can do some simple joins, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't make any changes to the existing Widget tables, you could do:

```
UserWidget
==========
UserWidgetID <-- PK, autoincrement
UserID <-- int
GuidKey <-- NULLable GUID
IntKey <-- NULLable int
Type <-- varchar ('WidgetA' or 'WidgetB')
```

Your query would then look like:

```
select uw.UserID, a.*, b.*
from UserWidget uw
left outer join WidgetA a on uw.Type = 'WidgetA' and uw.GuidKey = a.WidgetAID
left outer join WidgetB b on uw.Type = 'WidgetB' and uw.IntKey = b.WidgetBID
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you need inheritance in relational DBMS. You'll create a generic Widget table with auto-increment key and store its primary key in the two WidgetA and WidgetB tables as foreign keys. Now you can treat both kinds of Widgets as one, since they both have Widget's id.

Was that clear enough?

EDIT

Here are my words in ERD:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just store both IDs as a string (varchar):

```
UserID
WidgetID
```

Query:

```
Select *
From Favorite f
    Inner Join WidgetA a on f.WidgetID = Cast(a.WidgetID as varchar(max))
    Inner Join WidgetB b on f.WidgetID = Cast(b.WidgetID as varchar(max))
Where f.UserID = @userid
```